# Replace part of df column with values defined in Series/dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a column in a `DataFrame` that often has repeat indexes. Some indexes have exceptions and need to be changed based on another `Series` I've made, while the rest of the indices are fine as is. The `Series` indices are unique.

Here's a couple variables to illustrate

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'hi':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, index=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
Out[52]: 
   hi
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
3   6
4   7

exceptions = pd.Series(data=[90, 95], index=[2, 4])
Out[36]: 
2    90
4    95
```

I would like to do set the df to ...

```
   hi
1   1
1   2
1   3
2  90
2  90
3   6
4  95
```

What's a clean way to do this? I'm a bit new to Pandas, my thoughts are just to loop but I don't think that's the proper way to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the index in `exceptions` is guaranteed to be a subset of `df` indexes we can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and the [`Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html) to assign the values:

```
df.loc[exceptions.index, 'hi'] = exceptions
```

We can use [`index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) if we have extra values in `exceptions` that does not or should not align in `df`:

```
exceptions = pd.Series(data=[90, 95, 100], index=[2, 4, 5])
df.loc[exceptions.index.intersection(df.index, sort=False), 'hi'] = exceptions
```

`df`:

```
   hi
1   1
1   2
1   3
2  90
2  90
3   6
4  95
```

Comment: Wow that's beautiful, thank you. I was close haha, I had the loc and exceptions.index idea last week but had no idea you could just.. set it like that and ended up stuck

Comment: Also the series indices are indeed a subset of the df indices =p but ty for showing the case where it wasn't

Comment: Nice. Maybe that will help someone else down the line then.